# How can I make 'clickable' elements have selectable text on iOS touch devices?

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I have an element (a `div`) that has a number of javascript touch and mouse handlers on it. Apparently, this means the element is ['clickable'](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html), and it seems you are not able to select text on clickable elements on the iPad.

Is there any way around this? The event handlers are necessary for this to work right, but I'd also like users to be able to select and copy the text.

One solution is to make the div `contenteditable=true`. The event handlers still work, and I'm able to long-press to bring up the selector. But this would create its own set of problems and I'd like to avoid contenteditable if I can.

Comment: You could use use CSS to make the buttons appear on top of the div but  the are really before it.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work; the touch events only interact with what's on "top."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tinkering, I've found a workaround solution: Put the mouse and click handlers on the window instead of the element. Then, check the event `target` in the handler to see if the element of interest is what was clicked.

Not ideal, but it seems to work. I'm able to long-press and create a selection on an iPad.